# Controlling button toggle with window size reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which toggles a button state (#nav-icon) between open and 'close' (where the 'open' class is removed), Bootstrap navigation used. As well as what styles are applied to navigation divs if they are open (openNav) or closed (closeNav).

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#nav-icon').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
 });
});

let opened = false; // set the nav as closed by default
function toggleNav() {
  if(!opened) { // if opened is false (ie nav is closed), open the nav
   openNav()
  } else { // else, if opened is true (ie nav is open), close the nav
   closeNav();
  }
 opened = !opened;
 }

function openNav() {
  $('#navWrap').addClass('openHeight').removeClass('closeHeight');
  $('#main').addClass('openMargin').removeClass('closeMargin');
}

function closeNav() {
  $('#navWrap').removeClass('openHeight').addClass('closeHeight');
  $('#main').removeClass('openMargin').addClass('closeMargin');
}
```

html

```
<button id="nav-icon" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" onclick="toggleNav()"> ... </button>
```

What I want to do is 'reset' the navigation and nav-icon button whenever the window is resized (basically apply the 'closeNav' code and have 'open' removed from nav-icon when resized). I tried adding this to the bottom:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
$('#nav-icon').removeClass('open');
$('#navWrap').removeClass('openHeight').addClass('closeHeight');
$('#main').removeClass('openMargin').addClass('closeMargin');
});
```

Adding this, when the window is resized it seems to work, but then clicking the button doesn't have any effect, and the states then become out of order (button indicates closed when it's open and vice versa).

EDIT: basically wanting to add the button click to the open/close nav code, removing the toggle but keeping the click event.

*Also open to suggestions to clean-up/combine code where possible

Comment: According to this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82gb1uzv/) with the code you provided, it's behaving as you intend. Only difference is I removed the `onclick` and added the function to `click` handler.

Comment: post u r relevant  html code also.

Comment: I'm not sure the fiddle shows my issue. My button adds classes to those navigation elements. but once you resize the window the first click doesn't seem to do anything but change the button state (removes 'open' class) but doesn't seem to add the other classes. but it does on the second click, but then the open state is off and the nav is open

Comment: In terms of relevant html, the button is really it. The navigation sits at the top of the window. margin and height css makes it 'open' and 'close'